# Specific Regex for nubmers with commas and hyphens

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a filename i need to validate using preg_match in PHP, but i dont know much about regex patterns to fix my issue.

The string i am trying to validate is
2 numbers (0-9), a comma, 2 numbers (0-9), a hyphen, 2 numbers (0-9), a comma, 2 numbers (0-9)

An example is `47,60-51,00`

I have tried the following

> (-)?[0-9]+((,|-)[0-9]+)*

and

> ^[0-9][0-9,-]*-[0-9,-]*[0-9]$

But both seem to fail one way or another. Could someone help point me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to match the comma as a separate match but adding it to a character class `[0-9,-]` it can also match a digit or `-`

To match that format in a more specific way, you could use this pattern with a quantifier `{2}` to repeat matching a digit and match the comma's and hyphen at the expected position.

```
^[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/djsDiQ/1)

If you want the match to start with an optional hyphen you could start the pattern with `^-?`

Comment: This works, thank you so much! I'll accept in 7 when i can